# JavaScript filter an array and map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I've an array of objects.
Sample object is like this

```
 {
    dish_name: { id: 1297, name: "Bellingham Estate Sauvignon Blanc" },
    dish_has_categories: [
      {
        dishCatId: 11
      },
      {
        dishCatId: 12
      }
    ],
    id:1
  },
```

I want to filter objects where it's `dish_has_categories` array should have an object where `dishCatId` = 11 and also I want to map this array to minimal format.

**This is my data set**.

```js
const data = [
  {
    dish_name: { id: 1297, name: "Bellingham Estate Sauvignon Blanc" },
    dish_has_categories: [
      {
        dishCatId: 11
      },
      {
        dishCatId: 12
      }
    ],
    id:1
  },
  {
    dish_name: { id: 3432, name: "Burger" },
    dish_has_categories: [
      {
        dishCatId: 7
      },
      {
        dishCatId: 9
      }
    ],
    id:2
  },
  {
    dish_name: { id: 4593, name: "Hoppers" },
    dish_has_categories: [
      {
        dishCatId: 11
      },
      {
        dishCatId: 12
      }
    ],
    id:3
  },
  {
    dish_name: { id: 8709, name: "Bulsai" },
    dish_has_categories: [
      {
        dishCatId: 2
      },
      {
        dishCatId: 6
      }
    ],
    id:4
  }
];
```

**This is my expected results.**

```js
[
  {
    name: "Bellingham Estate Sauvignon Blanc",
    id: 1
  },

  {
    name: "Hoppers",
    id: 3
  }
];
```

For the filtering thing I did

```
data.filter(e=> e.dish_has_categories.find(el=> el.dishCatId = 11))
```

But it seems not working. How do I achieve this using JavaScript?

Comment: `el.dishCatId = 11` that assigns `11` to `el.dishCatId`. You want to check for equality, so use `==` or `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Assignment `=` to Strict equality operator `===` like:

```js
const data = [ { dish_name: { id: 1297, name: "Bellingham Estate Sauvignon Blanc" }, dish_has_categories: [ { dishCatId: 11 }, { dishCatId: 12 } ], id:1 }, { dish_name: { id: 3432, name: "Burger" }, dish_has_categories: [ { dishCatId: 7 }, { dishCatId: 9 } ], id:2 }, { dish_name: { id: 4593, name: "Hoppers" }, dish_has_categories: [ { dishCatId: 11 }, { dishCatId: 12 } ], id:3 }, { dish_name: { id: 8709, name: "Bulsai" }, dish_has_categories: [ { dishCatId: 2 }, { dishCatId: 6 } ], id:4 } ];

const result = data
.filter(e=> e.dish_has_categories.find(el => el.dishCatId === 11))
.map(res=>({id: res.id, name: res.dish_name.name}));


console.log(result)
```